# Shuffle find results that works with whitespaces

Tags: linux, bash

I am searching for all files in WAV format and create from them a single output file, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

AUDIO_PATH="$1"
OUTPUT_FILE="$2"
SEED="$3"

get_fixed_random()
{
  openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:$SEED -nosalt </dev/zero 2>/dev/null
}

AUDIO_FILES=$(find -L $AUDIO_PATH -name '*.wav' | shuf --random-source=<(get_fixed_random))

# This writes all WAV to a single output file
for file in $AUDIO_FILES; do
    [ ! -e "$file" ] || ffmpeg -i "$file" -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 48000 -
done > $OUTPUT_FILE
```

The trouble is, this doesn't work if files contain whitespaces, and the reason for it has been discussed e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343727/filenames-with-spaces-breaking-for-loop-find-command). I tried to applying this approach, that is to use

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
```

construct, but I am unable to get the syntax right. Help?

Comment: To read zero separated stream you have to have zero separated stream in the first place. `[ ! -e "$file" ] ||` - double negation? Why not `[[ -e ... ]] &&`? And is there a reason why are you checking if file exists after finding the file?

Comment: `find -L $AUDIO_PATH` will break if `$AUDIO_PATH` contains whitespace. Please familiarise yourself with the principles of quoting and how it influences word splitting in Bash : https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting .

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I know, that was the point of the question. The cited post discusses it in detail, it's just I didn't know how to apply a proper solution.

Comment: @KamilCuk There were elements of cargo cult programming here. As you noted, that check didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `for file in $something`. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net

To handle whitespace use zero separated streams.

In shell, try to write one long pipelines. Along:

```
find -L "$AUDIO_PATH" ... -print0 |
shuf -z ... |
xargs -0 -I{} ffmpeg -i {} ... - > "$OUTPUTFILE"
```

Prefer to use lowercase variables in scripts.

The `-z` `-0` `-print0` etc. options are supported by GNU tools.

You could do `xargs -P<NUM>` to parallelize execution, but it will mess with the output. You may explore GNU `parallel` to parallelize execution and stay with a sequenced output.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips on bash programming. The approach is cleaner than the original one and works flawlessly.